# Empty HttpContext.Current.Request.Files in WCF Service

Tags: wcf, html, file-upload, wcf-data-services, httpcontext

I'm trying to upload files form a html5 page to a WCF Service but the `Files` object in the `HttpContext.Current.Request` is empty.

Any Idea?

my WCF Service:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class FileUploader
{
    // test file uploader
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    public string UploadFile()
    {
        string fileName = "no file selected";

        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        if (context != null)
        {
            if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                fileName = context.Request.Files[0].FileName;
            }
        }

        return fileName;
    }
}
```

The calling javascript is:

```
function UploadFile() {

    FileUploader.UploadFile(HandleUploadResponse);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584939/html-form-post-to-wcf-service